# Dart - TypeScript's "conditional types" alternative

Tags: dart

I am trying to achieve a type which receives a `statusName`, and returns the matching `StatusType`.
coming from the TypeScript community, I could do something like this:

```
type StatusMetaData<T extends StatusName> = T extends OnTheWay ? OnTheWayData :T extends Completed ? CompletedData : DefaultStatusData
```

Is there a way to achieve that in dart?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

You can't have a type definition which depends non-compositionally on the type argument. Dart type arguments are "generics", which means that the code or definition a type parameter is available in can only use it *generically*.

So, what problem are you actually trying to solve.

Consider this code:

```dart
bool isSubtype<S, T>() => <S>[] is List<T>;

void runeWithStatusMetaData<T extends StatusName>(
    void Function<X>() action) {
  if (isSubtype<T, OnTheWay>()) {
    action<OnTheWayData>();
  } else if (isSubtype<T, Completed>()) {
    action<CompletedData>();
  } else { 
    action<DefaultStatusData>();
  }
}
```

That code allows you to inspect a type argument, and run other code with a different type argument depending on the first one.
I don't know if there are any relations between the `*Data` types. If so, the `<X>` type parameter could perhaps have a bound.